# How to use every second object in a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a for loop but I have the following problem:

`document.querySelectorAll('.msg.g_bot.bot.private.i ~ .msg .usr')[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML;` returns a **string**.

`document.querySelectorAll('.msg.g_bot.bot.private.i ~ .msg .usr')[1].childNodes[0].innerHTML;` returns **undefined**.

`document.querySelectorAll('.msg.g_bot.bot.private.i ~ .msg .usr')[2].childNodes[0].innerHTML;` returns a **string**.

`document.querySelectorAll('.msg.g_bot.bot.private.i ~ .msg .usr')[3].childNodes[0].innerHTML;` returns **undefined**.

That means every second property of 'childNodes' is undefined.

```
var username = [];
var usernameList = document.querySelectorAll('.msg.g_bot.bot.private.i ~ .msg .usr');
for (i of usernameList) {
    var name = document.querySelectorAll('.msg.g_bot.bot.private.i ~ .msg .usr')[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML;    
    if (name !== undefined) {
        username.push(name);
    }   
}
console.log(username);
```

When I run this script, I always get the error:

> Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

I have tried it with `if (name !== undefined) {` but I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Is it possible to use every second object only?

**Solution**

Maybe that was because I didn't understand how to use `for()` but this is how it would work:

```
var username = [];
var usernameList = document.querySelectorAll('.msg.g_bot.bot.private.i ~ .msg .usr');
for (i of usernameList) {
    if (i.childNodes) {
        var name = i.childNodes[0].innerHTML;    
        username.push(name);
    }    
}
console.log(username);
```

Comment: You might want to `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.msg.g_bot.bot.private.i ~ .msg .usr')[1])` to better understand exactly what the second user object is. I would also suggest replacing `name = document.querySelectorAll('.msg.g_bot.bot.private.i ~ .msg .usr')[i]` with `name = usernameList[i]`

Comment: if you know for sure that everytime the every other is undefined, you could put an interval of `i += 2`

Comment: @Thebluefish I did that already. It returns an element but it's something that I don't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
for (i of usernameList) {
    var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.msg.g_bot.bot.private.i ~ .msg .usr')[i];
    if (elem.childNodes) {
        var name = elem.childNodes[0].innerHTML;    
        if (name !== undefined) {
            username.push(name);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem you had was that if there was no `childNodes`, then you can't subscript it to get `childNodes[0]`, and certainly not `childNodes[0].name` -- it's not a matter of `name` being undefined, but a chain of references leading up to that being undefined.

Comment: Thank you, I used your code and mixed it with my own. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think think that this is a good approach to your problem, but it is what you're asking for:

```
var username = [];
var usernameList = document.querySelectorAll('.msg.g_bot.bot.private.i ~ .msg .usr:nth-child(even)');
for (i of usernameList) {
    var name = i.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
    if (name !== undefined) {
        username.push(name);
    }
}
console.log(username);
```

I think [kshetline's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49910001/1379329) answer is much less brittle.